# I am getting this error when I try to run react app with npm?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, npm, config

Getting this error when trying to run the react app with expo,
Tried running npm install expo-cli --global and also has package.json file.

Comment: What code caused the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What code is giving the error and have you already tried yourself to fix it? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using yarn. it's much better than npm. 
I was having a lot of problems with npm as well when I try to run the app or install any packages.
install yarn using
npm install yarn -g